# No iOS 13 simulator in Xcode 11 beta 5

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode11

I have installed Xcode 11 beta 5 and create a sample project

There is no iOS 13 simulators available:

[image]

When I go on `Add simulator` -> `Download more simulator`

iOS 13 is not available in list:

[image]

What should I do to install an iOS 13 simulator?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Xcode 11 beta doesn't seem to recognize the bundled Simulator SDK for iOS 13.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone know a workaround? (The problem is both on MacOS Mojave and the latest MacOS Catalina beta)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why it is happening, but you can create new simulators and it will work

- Click Add Additional Simulators from the menu where you would normally select the simulator (where you select your target)
- Click the + icon in the bottom left
- Create a new simulator - I selected iPhone XR and iOS 13

I was then able to select the iPhone XR as a run target

Comment: Got the same problem in Xcode 11 Gm. Got an error "Invalid argument" when I tried to add new iOS 13 simulator

Comment: Just found that simply RESTART the macOS did the trick... after restart everything works, IOS 13 Simulator available and usable

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have iOS 12.2 simulator downloaded, go to your project's "General" settings pane -> Under "Deployment Info",

make sure your target simulator version is the same as 12.2.

This is
[a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVLAG.png) of the "Deployment Info" settings pane. Ignore 13.2 in the image and replace it with your version.

I was able to use my downloaded simulators after making this change.